# JGit merge extra options

Tags: whitespace, git-merge, jgit

In Git command line, when we do the recursive merge, we can specify extra options with `-X`.

Eg: `git merge -s recursive -Xignore-all-space *branch*`

In JGit, is there a way to do this in the API ?

Best Regards.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no ready-to-use solultion to advise the merger to ignore whitespaces in JGit.

The `MergeCommand` has a `setStrategy()` method to choose the merge strategy, the equivalent to `--strategy`. And there is also a `RecursiveMerger` strategy, but it doesn't allow to specify further options.

I suggest to file an enhancement request https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/

If you really need this now, you may want to look into the `ResolveMerger` (base class of `RecursiveMerger`). It has a protected field `mergeAlgorithm` that may be assigned to a custom merge algorithm which ignores whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted a feature request.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471845